# Trying to deep clone an array of objects leaves out elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is in react/redux, below is the buggy case that executes in my reducer:

```
case actionTypes.UPDATE_PROJECT:
            const projectArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.projects));
            console.log(projectArr);
            console.log("PROJECTS BEFORE UPDATE: ", projectArr, state.projects);
```

state.projects is an object array, e.g.

```
projects: [{projName: "proj1"}, {projName: "proj2"}]
```

The thing is, if my state.projects was like the above, it somehow doesn't deep clone properly into projectArr. When I do `console.log(projectArr)`, the output is `[{projName: "proj1"}, {}]`.

When I do `console.log("PROJECTS BEFORE UPDATE: ", projectArr, state.projects)`, I get the full array (ie `[{projName: "proj1"}, {projName: "proj2"}]`).

Any hunches? I know that this is kind of sparse info but it's nested this rabbit hole code crap that would take pretty long to explain.

Comment: Are you certain that the output is `[{projectName: "proj1", {}]`? `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` does a deep copy across all browsers AFAIK.

Comment: Try logging `JSON.stringify(state.project)` as well. What is that output? Are these plain JavaScript objects?